# Argument of type 'Params' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have passed data via snapshot and am now trying to receive it but am getting the following error

> "[ts] Argument of type 'Params' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string'."

When I sent the data I done a JSON.stringify and the data looked like this.

```
[
  {
    "caseData": "{\"getAllInfo\":{\"ticket\":{\"internalNum\":\"2500024035\",\"comp\":\"29\",\"reportedDate\":\"2018-07-20\",\"reportedTime\":\"00:00\",\"forceNumCharge\":\"7035551\",\"offenceSequence\":\"1\",\"aggrievedParty\":\"1\"}}}"
  }
]
```

Now when I try to retrieve the data and do a JSON.parse I get the error mentioned above.

```
this.caseData = JSON.parse(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params);
```

Comment: What type is `this.caseData`?

Comment: it is `caseData: any;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but try with `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['caseData']`. In this case, you should probably put a `debugger` or a `console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params)` if you're doubting the way it's returned.

Comment: Yes this seems to giver back a cleaner data set and I can now filter through it